# When I ouput content(obtained from my database) in tinymce editor ,empty spaces are shown as Â

Tags: tinymce

How to get rid of this behavior.Will the Â  cause any problem if I output my content in an actual html page?

For example if I write **"   I am a newbie"** (note the empty spaces before 'I') into tinymce editor and save it to database it gets stored as: **"<p>   I am a newbie</p>"**.But when I ouput it again into tinymce editor(after fetching from database using php & codeigniter) it is shown as **"Â Â I am a newbie"**.
    The source code(in tinymce) appears to be

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Â&nbsp;Â&nbsp; I am a newbie</p>
```

Please help me out of this situation because if I save it back to the database then it now gets saved as the source code shown just above with these weird **Â**  characters.

Comment: This may be an encoding problem - are your pages set to use UTF-8 encoding in the head?

Comment: Yes you are right,its UTF-8.Please can you suggest how to get rid of this problem.As I stated in the question, the first time I write something into tinymce editor and save its contents to mysql database,it gets stored exactly as I have written it.But on fetching that same content back from the database and displaying it again(for editing) these weird 'Â ' characters appear in the editor in place of the empty spaces.Thank you

Comment: Is your database also setup to use UTF-8 encoding?  Every part of your system needs to use the same encoding or issues like this will happen.

Comment: @MichaelFromin it has encoding uft8mb4_unicode_ci.Any corrections needed here?